# Binary tree depth at leaves

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search, depth, tree-traversal

I am solving the following problem from a website: "Write a function to see if a binary tree is "superbalanced" (a new tree property we just made up).
A tree is "superbalanced" if the difference between the depths of any two leaf nodes is no greater than one."

The way that the website checks the depths difference between two nodes is by doing depth-first search and then appending the depth of every node visited to a list called depths, as long as the depth is not already in the list:

```
        if depth not in depths:
            depths.append(depth)

            # two ways we might now have an unbalanced tree:
            # 1) more than 2 different leaf depths
            # 2) 2 leaf depths that are more than 1 apart
            if (len(depths) > 2) or \
                (len(depths) == 2 and abs(depths[0] - depths[1]) > 1):
                return False
```

What I don't understand is, why do we have to check both the ways? Wouldn't it be enough to just check whether condition there are either more than 2 different leaf depths or 2 different leaf depths are more than one apart? Why is it useful to have both checks?

Code/Question quoted from source:InterviewCake.com

Comment: Good question; but since its more about the algorithm (and not an issue with the code), its better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid since when is SO not a suitable place to ask about algorithms?? the help page clearly states algorithms are an an acceptable topic...

Comment: Please show more code. The `now` in `we might now have` concerns me

Comment: Not entirely related to the question: this is a pretty silly property, since a tree with all nodes aligned at the left would be "superbalanced", since it would have only one leaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need both checks, sort of...

the first one is clearly not enough since you can have `len(depths)==2` and the difference between the two `>1`.

the 2nd condition, as it is written, can only work if `len(depth)` is exactly `2`.
you could have only this latter condition but then you'd need to iterate over all items in the `depth` list.

so basically it is designed this way to be as efficient as possible. you could argue that this is a case of over-optimization since the length of the `depths` list will never be greater than `3` and this is also the maximum number this check will be performed.

i would go with something like `max(depths) - min(depths) > 1` which is much more readable and intuitive and has negligible affect on performance.